# How do I create a line between each point?

Tags: p5.js

I want to create a tool similar to the pentool in photoshop/illustrator, but only using straight line. How do i create a line between each point? My first instinct was to push them into an Array, but I'm stack here, what do I do next?

Code: https://editor.p5js.org/AlexArek/sketches/4TZ1Y-6y0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're stuck because you're using `push()` inside a `for` loop that is conditioned by the length of the array you're trying to push into and which is empty. In other words, the code inside the for loop is never being executed. I'm not familiar with the *pentool*, but I'll assume you want to draw a straight line between a series of points, in which case this might help:

```js
let points = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  background(35);
}

function draw() {}

function mousePressed() {
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(10);
  point(mouseX, mouseY);
  points.push({x:mouseX, y:mouseY});
  if(points.length > 1)
    line(points[points.length-1].x, points[points.length-1].y, points[points.length-2].x, points[points.length-2].y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```